# Code::Blocks dependecy between projects

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am new to C++ and I am working with the IDE Code::Blocks on Windows.
I have a project **myProject** and
I have another project **myProjectTesting**, which depends on myProject.

I have setup myProject as a dependency for myProjectTesting, as explained in the [Code::Blocks documentation](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=The_build_process_of_Code::Blocks#Using_project_dependencies).

myProjectTesting contains only one file with the following code:

```
#include "Position.hpp"

int main()
{
    Position position(3, 4);

    return 0;
}
```

Position.hpp is a class header in **myProject**.
I have the following error when compiling with gcc:

```
undefined reference to `Position::Position(int, int)'.
```

Note that the line `Position position(3, 4);` runs fine If I use it inside **myProject**.

Position.hpp file:

```
/*
 * Position.hpp
 *
 *  Created on: 30/08/2014
 *      Author: Romain
 */

#ifndef POSITION_H_
#define POSITION_H_
#include <string>

class Position
{
public:

    Position(int _x, int _y);
    Position();
    Position deltaX(int delta);
    Position deltaY(int delta);
    Position deltaXY(int deltaX, int deltaY);
    int getX();
    int getY();
    std::string print();

private:

    int x;
    int y;
};

#endif /* POSITION_H_ */
```

Comment: Can you also post the `Position.hpp` code.

Comment: @Learner Sure, I have just added the file.

Comment: Your error suggest that `myProjectTesting` is not able to find the definition of `Position::Position(int, int)`. So my guess is that you have not link your `myProject` with `myProjectTesting` properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what my issue was (from the [CodeBlocks forum](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,19681.msg134393.html#msg134393))

Declaring (in Code::Blocks) a project as being dependent on another project, **only** affects the order of the project builds, i.e. myProject is built before myProjectTesting in my case.

But I still had to manually add the library myProject to the libraries being linked to from myProjectTesting.